# Why does this XOR result in a much smaller result?

Tags: binary, logic, bit-manipulation, xor

Here are some examples of XORs which are really throwing me for a loop:

```
Number 1:     100111111111111111111111
Number 2:     101001011001010010000011
XOR Result:     1110100110101101111100


Number 1:   101000000000000000000000
Number 2:   101001011001010010000011
XOR Result:      1011001010010000011
```

Why is the XOR result from the second set so much smaller? Number 2 is the same in both sets and Number 1 was increased only by 1 in the second set, yet the XOR result is so much different. Why is this happening? It seems like it's ignoring the first 5 bits in the second set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the the leading bits are the same, which would result in a `0` under an XOR operation and in numbers leading zeros are irrelevant.

`0010` is the same as `10`

(there is no difference)

```
Number 1:     100111111111111111111111
Number 2:     101001011001010010000011
XOR Result:   001110100110101101111100
```

Comment: That...makes perfect sense. Thank you!